# When were the spiders first observed on Mars?

Tags: mars, surface

On Mars, there are spider-looking features near the South pole that [might be caused by CO2 sublimation](https://www.uahirise.org/epo/nuggets/martian-spiders-lab.pdf). When were these features first observed on the surface of Mars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the impression these were first observed in images taken by the [Mars Orbiter Camera (MOC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Orbiter_Camera) of the Mars Global Surveyor, probably sometime between 1997 (arrival at Mars) and 1999 (when the main mapping program began) -- or possibly as late as 2000 (when they are first mentioned).

In [Piqueux et al. (2003)](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1029/2002JE002007), a paper specifically focused on the spiders, they say

> The term ‘‘spiders’’ was used by Kieffer [2000] (although the term may
> have originally been coined by Andy Ingersoll [H. Kieffer, personal
> communication, 2003]) and we use this term in this paper.

In [Kieffer (2000)](https://www.lpi.usra.edu/meetings/polar2000/pdf/4095.pdf) we find this statement

> Dark radially converging dendritic patterns are visible in MOC images
> of some portions of the spring polar cap [7]; these have been termed
> "black spiders" by the MOC team [8].

Unfortunately, the published version of that short conference proceeding article is missing all of the references after number [4], so I don't know if there is more specific useful information available. The conference at which Kieffer (2000) was presented was in August, 2000, so I'd put mid-2000 as the latest possible date.